# Save and populate DatePicker

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, datetime, datepicker, nullable

I have a windows phone 7 application where I´m using a "DatePicker" from the silverlight toolbox.

I´m trying to save the choosen DatePicker value, as suggestion I assign it to an DateTime structure so that I later can populate the same DatePicker with the saved DateTime value. Simple as it sounds, I don´t get it to work due to an error:

> Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.DateTime?' to 'System.DateTime'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)

when constructing the DateTime value as below:

```
DateTime saved = datePicker.Value;
```

The DateTime are to be saved for later use as following:

```
datePicker.Value = saved.Value;
```

Does the DatePicker not have a valid DateTime value? I´m new at this, what shall I do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Datepicker Value property is a `Nullable<DateTime>` (same as `DateTime?`).  This is so it can represent "nothing chosen".  (DateTime is a struct, so it can not be null).  Can you store a `Nullable<DateTime>` instead?  Otherwise, you can test if the `Nullable<DateTime>` has a value:

```
if (datePicker.Value.HasValue)
{
    //save
    DateTime saved = datePicker.Value.Value;
}
```

Comment: I´ve used a Nullable<DateTime> instead and now it works great. Thanks!